# WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/wdym/' failed: dashboard.js:2

Tags: python, django, websocket, real-time, django-channels

So I'm working on my personal django project to create a real-time web application using channel and websocket. But it shows this error: 'WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/wdym/' failed:  dashboard.js:2' in the console and this error: 'Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 50536)' from the terminal. Can you tell me what the issues are and the solution to it? Thanks!
I use:
python 3.10.11
channels 4.0.0
channels-redis 4.1.0

This is routing.py

```
`from django.urls import re_path
from .consumers import DashboardConsumer

# websocket url list
websocket_urlpatterns = [ 
    re_path('ws/wdym/',DashboardConsumer.as_asgi()),
    ]`
```

this is urls.py inside the application named game

```
`from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .consumers import DashboardConsumer

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"), 
    path("<int:id>",views.todo, name="todo"), 
    path("list/", views.list, name="list"),
    path('wdym/', views.dashboard, name="dashboard")
    
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
```

this is consumers.py

```
`from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer #import the websocket
import json

class DashboardConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    
    async def connect(self): 
        print('connection')
        await self.accept()
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({ 
            'type':'connection_established',
            'message': 'You are connected'
        }))

   
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):  
        print(f'connection closed with code: {close_code}')

    
    async def receive(self, text_data): 
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data) # get the data in json strings which get loaded to a json object.
        message = text_data_json["message"]
        sender = text_data_json["sender"]
        
        print("message",message, sender)

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({ # send data over a network connection. 
            'message': message,
            'sender': sender,
            }))`
```

this is dashboard.js

```
`const socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/wdym/');

socket.onmessage = function(e) { 
    let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log('Server: ' + data);
};

socket.onopen = function(e) { 
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({ 
        'message': 'Hello from client',
    }));
};

socket.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log('error')
}

console.log(socket);`
```

this is dashboard.html

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    {% extends "main/base.html" %}
    {% load static %}
<head>
    <title>{% block title %} Dashboard {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    woe
    <button id="clickBtn">yes</button>
    {% endblock content %}

    {% block scripts %}
        <script src="{% static 'dashboard.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock scripts %}

</body>
</html>`
```

this is asgi.py

```
`import os
import channels
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack #django authentication system. User needs to login in order to access the routing/url
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter # to utilize routing
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import game.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'webgame.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter (
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app, # http request are going to be handled by django_asgi_app
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator( # websocket request handled by those tings
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(game.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
`
```

this is settings.py

```
`from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-b2(4m_$^b=1ldz9o_!iol8%8a!dsc3w#th)w%v=q4@k&#hc&y@'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth', #authenticate users
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'game.apps.GameConfig',
    'register.apps.RegisterConfig',
    'realgame.apps.RealgameConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'channels',
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND' : 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'webgame.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'webgame.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'webgame.asgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# )

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # the url you to use in your views/temptlates
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') #the location of media file. media is the name of the folder


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK="bootstrap5"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ="/"
`
```

First, I've already review the code on each files, but I don't find any issues there. I also changed the python version to 3.10.0 and 3.9.6. I also changed the channels-redis version to 3.4.1. But still, the websocket failed to connect.